# How to add a constant spread to an existing YieldTermStructure object in Quantlib

Tags: c++, quantlib

I would really appreciate your inputs on moving from a YieldTermStructure pointer to that of adding a spread as below::

```
boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> depoFutSwapTermStructure(new PiecewiseYieldCurve<Discount,
        LogLinear>(settlementDate, depoFutSwapInstruments_New, termStructureDayCounter, 1.0e-15));
```

I tried adding a spread of 50 bps as below...

```
double OC_Spread(0.50 / 100);
Rate OCSQuote = OC_Spread;
boost::shared_ptr<Quote> OCS_Handler(new SimpleQuote(OCSQuote));
```

I then proceed to create a zerospreaded object as below:

```
ZeroSpreadedTermStructure Z_Spread(Handle<YieldTermStructure>(*depoFutSwapTermStructure), Handle<Quote>(OCS_Handler));
```

But now I am stuck as the code repeatedly breaks down if I go on ahead to do anything like

```
Z_Spread.zeroYieldImpl;
```

What is the issue with above code. I have tried several flavors of above approach and failed on all the fronts.

Also is there a native way of calling directly the discount function just like as I do now with the TermStructure object prior to adding the spread currently as below???

```
depoFutSwapTermStructure->discount(*it)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you got your interfaces a bit mixed up.  The `zeroYieldImpl` method you're trying to call on your `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` is protected, so you can't use it from your code (at least, that's how I'm guessing your code breaks, since you're not reporting the error you get).

The way you interact with the curve you created is through the public `YieldTermStructure` interface that it inherits; that includes the `discount` method that you want to call, as well as methods such as `zeroRate` or `forwardRate`.

Again, it's hard to say why your call to `discount` fails precisely, since you're not quoting the error and you're not saying what `*it` is in the call.  From the initialization you do report, and from the call you wrote, I'm guessing that you might have instantiated a `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` object but you're trying to use it with the `->` syntax as if it were a pointer. If that's the case, calling `Z_Spread.discount(*it)` should work instead (assuming `*it` resolves to a number).

If that's not the problem, I'm afraid you'll have to add a few more details to your question.

Finally, for a more general treatment of term structures in QuantLib, you can read [here](http://www.implementingquantlib.com/2013/09/chapter-3-part-1-of-n-term-structures.html) and [here](http://www.implementingquantlib.com/2013/09/chapter-3-part-2-of-n-yield-term.html).